# Django 'Post' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to append a quoted pots to user's post before saving it.

Here is the view:

```
@login_required
def quote_reply(request, quote_id):
    tform = PostForm()
    print 'quote_id is:' + quote_id
    quote = Post.objects.get(pk = quote_id)
    topic_id = quote.topic_id
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id= topic_id)
    print 'quote is' + quote.body

    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = PostForm(request.POST)


        if post.is_valid():
            p = post.save(commit = False)
            p.topic = topic
            p.title = post.cleaned_data['title']
            p.body = post.cleaned_data['body']
            p['body'].append(str(quote))  #problematic line
            p.creator = request.user
            p.user_ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']

            if len(p.title)< 1:
                            p.title=p.body[:60]            
            p.save()

            tid = int(topic_id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/forum/topic/%s'  % topic_id)

    else:
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = tform
        args['post'] = quote
        args['topic_id'] = topic_id
        return render_to_response('myforum/qoute_reply.html', args, 
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I tried also tried

```
p['body'].append(unicode(quote))
```

but gives the same error.

Appreciate your help to resolve this.

Update: Here is the Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    user_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s - %s - %s" % (self.creator, self.topic, self.title)

    def short(self):
        return u"%s - %s\n%s" % (self.creator, self.title, self.created.strftime("%b %d, %I:%M %p"))

    short.allow_tags = True
```

Not sure what to do.

Comment: can you show your `Post` model ?

Comment: Why are you using `p['body']` in that line? That's your error, but I'm not clear what you're intending to do that would make you use that rather than `p.body`.

Comment: @karthikr I just added the model.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I also tried `p.body` which yeilds to: `'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: do you have unicode specified on all the foreign key attributes used in `__unicode__` ? My guess is, something is going wrong while serialization: Try `self.creator.username, self.topic.title, self.title`, etc..

Comment: Right, strings and unicode objects are immutable. You have to create a new one and assign that to `p.body`. I'd do that in one line, `p.body = post.cleaned_data['body'] + unicode(quote)`.

Comment: @karthikr, all relevant models have ` def __unicode__(self):` in them.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, the one line p.body yeilds to: `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: There's no reason it would need to use the ascii implicit decode if you use `unicode(quote)` rather than `str(quote`), and if you're using standard widgets and form fields so that `cleaned_data['body']` is also a Unicode object.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper right. Please elaborate and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that `p` is a model instance, which does not support dict-style attribute access syntax. To access the `post` attribute, use the standard dot syntax, `p.post`.

The second problem is that you can't use `append` to change a Unicode or string object - they're immutable. Instead, you should create a new Unicode object containing the content you want and assign that. For instance:

```
p.post = post.cleaned_data['body'] + unicode(quote)
```